# Change the tab size on an element with word-wrap: pre?

Tags: css, word-wrap, tab-size

I have an element that is similar to a  tag (because it has word-wrap: pre;) to display code on a website. The only problem is that the tab size is too large and causes the element to horizontally scroll often because it is of fixed width.

Is it possible to change the tab size?

Comment: Similar to a tag?  Or similar to a tab?

Comment: I think he probably meant "Similar to a <pre> tag" and the HTML tag disappeared.

Comment: There is extension in Mozilla browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-tab-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace tabs with spaces.  Then you could control exactly the size of the indents.

Answer (score 0):

We need some more clarity into your question, but are you perchance looking for the `text-indent` css property?  You can set the indentation amount, e.g.:

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
  text-indent: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `text-indent` only applies to the first line of text in the matching element(s): http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#indentation-prop